# resize bitmap image in cell of datagridview

Tags: c#, image, image-resizing

still having an issue of resizing my image.

Using c sharp.net 4.0 winforms and MS Visual Studio 2010.

heres the code I currently have:

```
private void ShowArrow()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow paretoRow in ParetoGrid.Rows)
        {
            if ((paretoRow.Cells["Pareto6"].Value != null) && (Convert.ToInt32(paretoRow.Cells["CurrentPareto"].Value) < (Convert.ToInt32(paretoRow.Cells["NewPareto"].Value))))
            {
                downArrow.Width = 2; 
                downArrow.Height = 2;
                paretoRow.Cells["p1"].Value = downArrow; 
            }
            else if ((paretoRow.Cells["Pareto6"].Value != null) && (Convert.ToInt32(paretoRow.Cells["CurrentPareto"].Value) > (Convert.ToInt32(paretoRow.Cells["NewPareto"].Value))))
            {
                //ParetoGrid.Rows[paretoRow.Index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                paretoRow.Cells["p1"].Value = upArrow;
            }
        }
    }
```

but when I try to edit the image size it says that the image is read only?
Is this a nice one liner to resize an image?  or is there a better way?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the 'read-only' property of your image object and proceed with it. 
Suppose your variable is BitmapImage myImage.

```
bool isReadOnly = myImage.IsSealed;
```

There is another method called SetValue. Hope this helps.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, if you have an Image object:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage.aspx

Not a one-liner solution actually, but it is close to it. You may propably want to generate the resized image beforehand and use that later on.